# Converting link-like texts to links

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I just noticed some very strange behaviour in my pdf.
I have a link in there (just pure text!) "www.example.com".

Now when I view this in my reader (Sumatra & Adobe) this link has a "hand" icon and I'm able to click on it. Even though I just put it as real text in there.

So I converted it to PS (pdftops  ), found the text (\000w\000w\000w etc), and just changed the first "W" to "A".
Then I convert it via ps2pdf back into a PDF file, and wonder... No link anymore. (it shows now aww.example.com).

So, back to the ps file, I change the a again to w, and re-convert.

Suddenly the link is there again.

Because of this I'm pretty certain this is some feature with the reader that it's being too smart for its own good.

Which brings me to my question: how can I turn this off? Is there any comment/setting I can give which would disable this behaviour for that specific PDF file?
[the problem is that the reader is just adding "http://" in front of it to create the link, and when clicking, my reader warns me that the link is not safe. Talking about insults and injuries!]

Thanks!

Comment: I think Adobe looks for `(protocol)://(address)` and converts each result to a link. There should be an option to disable automatic detection, try to look for `Edit => Preferences => General => Create Links from URLs`

Comment: @Signo: thanks, but I didn't add "http" in front of it. Also I would like to have it automatically disabled for that specific pdf (if at all possible that is).

Comment: That feature is a viewer specific feature which is active for all or for no documents.